# Postgresql simple query on moderately large table is extremely slow

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a PostgresSQL DB on Google SQL :

- 4 vCPUS
- 15 GB RAM
- 55 GB SSD

The relevant schema is :

```
postgres=> \d device;
                        Table "public.device"
        Column          |          Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
id                      | uuid                    |           | not null |
brand                   | character varying(255)  |           |          |
model                   | character varying(255)  |           |          |
serialnumber            | character varying(255)  |           |          |
[...]
Indexes:
    "device_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
[...]
Referenced by:
    TABLE "application" CONSTRAINT "fk_application_device_id_device" FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES device(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
[...]

postgres=> \d application;
                        Table "public.application"
          Column           |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
id                         | uuid                   |           | not null |
device_id                  | uuid                   |           | not null |
packagename                | character varying(255) |           |          |
versionname                | character varying(255) |           |          |
[...]
Indexes:
    "application_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "application_device_id_packagename_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (device_id, packagename)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_application_device_id_device" FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES device(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
[...]
```

Volumetry :

- `device` table: 16k rows
- `application`: 3.6M rows

When trying something as simple as:

```
select count(id) from application;
```

The query took 900 seconds (sic) to count those 3.6M rows.

Here is the execution plan:

```
postgres=> explain analyze select count(id) from application;
                                                                            QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1245180.18..1245180.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=311470.250..311496.933 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Gather  (cost=1245179.96..1245180.17 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=311470.225..311496.919 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1244179.96..1244179.97 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=311463.287..311463.289 rows=1 loops=3)
            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on application  (cost=0.00..1234885.77 rows=3717677 width=16) (actual time=79.783..311296.505 rows=1202169 loops=3)
Planning Time: 0.083 ms
Execution Time: 311497.021 ms
(8 rows)
```

It seems like everything (like keys and indexes) is correctly set, so what could be the reason for this simple query to take so long ?

Comment: Maybe an explanation [Slow Counting](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting), [Count estimate](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate)

Comment: @Philippe Yes, I saw this page, but isn't it weird that it takes so long, even if it reads every row ? Anyway, using estimates is not acceptable, as I don't know how this could be used through regular DB tools (ORM and such), plus our need won't be met with estimates only...

Comment: Yes I can understand your dismay, but to my knowledge there are no other way to get this information.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google SQL - do they provide guarantees on IOPS ? On Azure Database we encountered situations when we hit IOPS limit when  **all** operations becomes slow without any visible reasons for that. E.g. you  reindex a table or rebuild matview and then simple key lookups starts taking seconds to complete.

Comment: Another point: I would rather expect `Index Only Scan using application_pkey` than `Seq Scan on application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look deeper to determine the cause:

- turn on `track_io_timing` in the PostgreSQL configuration so that you can see how long I/O takes
- use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to see how many 8kB blocks are touched

If there number of blocks is very high, your table is bloated (consists mostly of nothing), and the sequential scan takes so long because it has to read all that empty space. `VACUUM (FULL)` can help with that.

If the block count is as you would expect, the problem is that your storage is too slow.

Comment: You're right, the table was bloated by a lot of deletes / inserts. The `VACUUM (FULL)` fixed it, and some persistence approaches will have to be changed. Thanks!